# JavaScript out of memory error: UDF thread memory limit exceeded-Snowflake

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I am trying to merge two variant rows using javascript UDF.However each of my variant row has around 12500 keys.
My udf definition is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_json(EXT_ROW VARIANT, STG_ROW VARIANT)
    RETURNS variant
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS 
    $$
    function extend(ext, stg) {
      if(ext == null)ext=stg
      for (var key in stg) {
          if (stg.hasOwnProperty(key)) ext[key] = stg[key];
      }
      return ext;
    }
    return extend(EXT_ROW, STG_ROW)
    $$;
```

From snowflake documentation , I came to know in case if script uses too much memory or runs into infinite loop then udf fails.So i tried to remove loop in my above function and makes it as below:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_json_v1(EXT_ROW VARIANT, STG_ROW
 VARIANT)
     RETURNS variant
     LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
     AS 
     $$
     function extend(ext, stg) {
       if(ext == null)ext=stg
       let merged_row = Object.assign(ext, stg);
       return merged_row;
     }
     return extend(EXT_ROW, STG_ROW)
     $$;
```

still function is throwing error.Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing VARIANT with OBJECT and eliminating the internal wrapper function may remove some overhead.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_json_v1(EXT_ROW OBJECT, STG_ROW OBJECT)
RETURNS OBJECT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS 
$$
 return EXT_ROW ? Object.assign(EXT_ROW, STG_ROW) : STG_ROW
$$;
```

Failing that, you could increase the warehouse size.  Also check the query profile in case something else is causing the problem.

Comment: If rewriting the function doesn't resolve the issue (though definitely try this), you may be able to contact Snowflake Support for additional assistance.